# Isomorphism $E\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}\cong E\oplus \bar{E} $ for complex bundle

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

The isomorphism $$E\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}\cong E\oplus \bar{E} $$ for a complex bundle $E$ it's supposed to be an easy exercise, ($\bar{E}$ is the conjugate bundle) but I can't prove fibre-wise linearity of the obvious map.

My idea is to define the map as $$\alpha \otimes (x+iy) \mapsto (x\cdot \alpha,iy \cdot \alpha)$$

But it's unclear to me how to show that the second component is conjugate-linear. In the domain, the only complex action I can think of is the diagonal action but then according to my computations the map is no more $\mathbb{C}$-linear. I think the problem is that I'm not considering the right action on the left side

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Maybe $\alpha\otimes (x+iy)\mapsto (x.\alpha,y.\alpha)$ is better.

Comment: I think the action on the left side is $\alpha\cdot(e\otimes \beta)=(\alpha e)\otimes \beta$, where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$. A diagonal action of $\mathbb{C}$ on $E\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$ doesn't seem like it would respect the $\mathbb{R}$-linearity of the tensor product, e.g., $$2\cdot(e\otimes\beta)=2e\otimes 2\beta=(4e)\otimes\beta=4(e\otimes\beta)$$ seems wrong.

Comment: Another approach would be to show $\mathbb C =\mathbb R\oplus\overline{\mathbb R}$ and then $E\otimes \mathbb C=E\otimes(\mathbb R\oplus\overline{\mathbb R})$ $=E\otimes\mathbb R \oplus E\otimes \overline{\mathbb R}=E\oplus\overline E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*remark: more precisely, you're trying construct the isomorphism 
$r(E)\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}\cong E\oplus \bar{E}$,
where $r$ is the forgetful functor from the category of $\mathbb C$-bundles to the category of $\mathbb R$-bundles*

the map from your example is not bijective and not $\mathbb C$-linear. but if you take map $f:\alpha\otimes z\mapsto (\alpha\cdot z,\alpha\cdot\bar z)$, it will be so.

indeed, 
$f(\alpha\otimes z)\cdot w=
(\alpha\cdot z,\alpha\cdot\bar z)\cdot w=
(\alpha\cdot z\cdot w,\alpha\cdot\bar z\cdot\bar w)=
f(\alpha\otimes z\cdot w)$, so $f$ is $\mathbb C$-linear.

and the inverse map can be defined as 
$(\alpha,\beta)\mapsto \frac{\alpha+\beta}2\otimes1-i\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\otimes i$. $ $ let's check it!

$(\alpha,\beta)
\mapsto 
\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\otimes1-i\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\otimes i
\mapsto
(\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\cdot1,\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\cdot1)+
(-i\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\cdot i,+i\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\cdot i)=
(\alpha,\beta)$.

$\alpha\otimes 1+\beta\otimes i
\mapsto 
(\alpha,\alpha)+(\beta\cdot i,-\beta\cdot i)
\mapsto
\frac{\alpha+\alpha}2\otimes 1-i\frac{\alpha-\alpha}2\otimes i+
\frac{\beta i-\beta i}2\otimes 1 -i\frac{\beta i+\beta i}2\otimes i=
\alpha\otimes 1+\beta\otimes i
$

Comment: Dear Andrey, thanks a lot for the answer, I've got a few doubts about it though: it's unclear to me why the inverse is defined as you have suggested, can't prove that it is really the inverse. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Anyway, the map you provided is easily seen to be injective, therefore it's fibrewise isomorphism

Comment: @LuigiM sorry, the inverce map must be $(a,b)\mapsto\frac{a+b}2\otimes1-i\frac{a-b}2\otimes i$ instead of $(a,b)\mapsto\frac{a+b}2\otimes1+\frac{a-b}2\otimes i$